# Calculating Turn Angles given GeoCoordinates

Tags: python-3.x, geometry, geospatial, trigonometry, angle

I'm given three GPS points for instance in terms of their geocoordinates (longitude, latitude) that are relatively close to each other:

```
p1 = (p1_lon, p1_lat)
p2 = (p2_lon, p2_lat)
p3 = (p3_lon, p3_lat)
```

Suppose a path exists from `p1` to `p2` (called segment C), then `p2` to `p3` (called segment A). Then suppose I draw a direct line from `p1` to `p3` (called segment B). How can I compute for the turn angle? Is that the angle formed between segments C and A (i.e., opposite segment B). Or should I subtract this angle from 180 degrees (or `np.pi` radians) to obtain the turn angle?

Also, in terms of computing for the aforementioned angle, I assume that the Law of Cosines for Triangles is required?

```
B**2 = A**2 + C**2 - 2*A*C*cos(theta)
```

where `theta` is the angle that we are solving. So rearranging the equation, we get:

```
theta = np.arccos((B**2 - A**2 - C**2)/(-2*A*C))
```

But I'm getting `nan`. I'm led to believe that using cosine or inverse cosine is problematic especially for small distances/angles. I'm currently using the geodesic distance which I thought is the most accurate distances when measuring distance between two geocoordinates. I think I read somewhere about haversine distance? But I'm not sure what it is and if it is accurate to use for measuring distances. Will it help in calculating the `theta` much easily and faster avoiding the nans. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What about using a geodesic library?  For example GeographicLib.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Thinko I'm sorry, I don't follow. I checked out this library as you suggested: https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/python/code.html, but it seems like it only calculates distances/geodesic distances. However, I already have been using a method from geopy. So measuring geodesic distances is not an issue. My problem is how to compute for turn angles.

Comment: It is not clear what angle you want.  I wrote answer, but re-reading question, I'm not sure that it addresses your needs.  Could you show a simple picture?

Comment: @M.Fire, GeographicLib not only measures distances, but also calculates the initial and final headings when travelling from one location to another.  When you know the headings, you can calculate the turning angles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate azimuth `a21` from `p2` to `p1` (note it is not the same as azimuth from `p1` to `p2`!), then azimuth `a23` from `p2` to `p3`, then calculate turn angle as

```
turn = a32 - (a21 + 180)
```

and correct it to range `0..360` or `-180..180` if needed (adding/subtracting 360)

Form moving A-B-C and turn after B:

[image]

To get azimuth, you can use appropriate Python geolibrary  - I see that geographiclib contains it.

Answer (score 0):

@MBo I think I should have drawn a picture in the first place. Anyways, I drew a picture of what I mean. `theta` here is the angle formed with segment `p1` to `p2` when the object moves from `p2` to `p3`. It also occurred to me that a sharper turn induces a larger turning angle `alpha` (second case) while the first case should only have smaller turning angle as the turn is not that sharp compared to the second one. So I believe we can compute `alpha` by subtracting 180 degrees minus the `theta` (this makes sense because if `p1` and `p3` form a straight line with `p2` on that line, i.e.  the points are collinear with `p2` in the middle of the other two points, then the object went straight direction from `p2` so the turn angle is 0 degrees; and if they are all collinear still but either `p1` or `p3` is in the middle of `p2` and `p3` or `p1`, then we'll know the object went backwards and so the turn is 180 degrees). This should all happen symmetrically as well on the other side. Clearly, the turn angles can only be between [0,180].

The problem then arises with calculating `theta`. Because the three points are GPS coordinates and very small, the angle can be small as well. And thus applying the cosines/arccosines can be ill-conditioned as some articles I've read online suggest. I'm not sure what is a turn around for this. Can I compute such angles without having to use the cosines/arccosines? And when you mentioned about azimuth, did you mean I have to compute it and use it? Why would we need it and how can it help in the problem?
[image]

Comment: Azimuth(bearing,heading) calculation involves spherical trigonometry, not plain one (for example, angle sum in spherical triangle differs from 180 degrees). Now I see that my answer is what you need. If you don't want geolinraries, look at bearing formula [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). And yes, calculations for small values might cause computational errors. But we cannot exclude trig. functions usage when calculate angles.